# Apache (FCGI?) session distribution

Tags: apache, apache2, fastcgi

Hopefully this is a simple question, since I'm fairly new to the inner workings of Apache. For those unfamiliar with FCGI, it creates a cgi process that continues running between requests, effectively creating a instance that lasts as long as the user needs. It does this by starting an executable cgi file and directing future requests into that running program (as I understand it).

My question is this: Is there a way to have apache create a new instance of this program for every new user (as determined by cookies, IP address, whatever) and then redirect subsequent requests from that user to the same process they initialized? I.E.

`user1 requests test.fcgi 

user1 creates PID 100 

user2 requests test.fcgi 

user2 creates PID 101 

user1 requests test.fcgi 

user1 directed to running PID 100 

user2 requests test.fcgi 

user2 directed to running PID 101`

If this requires new modules or already existing programs, that's fine. If it's something I'll have to code myself, could you point me in the right direction to start?

For details: I'm running apache 2.2.12 on an EC2 machine with libapache2-mod-fcgid installed from the ubuntu repositories.

Thank you

Comment: Surely you don't want a separate process for each user? Otherwise if you have 1000 unique visitors, you'll have 1000 processes running. Maybe you mean it's acceptable for multiple visitors to share a process, but that each visitor should always map onto the same process on each visit.

Comment: We need users to be able to run the program independently of each other but to be able to keep a running session. Ideally we'd have strict processor use limits, timeout limits, and we would utilize the cloud load-distribution of the EC2 network. This seems like the only way to do it without a queue of requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't get session affinity with FastCGI, and since (in the configuration that's nearly always used), all of the child processes are listening on the same socket and relying on the kernel to distribute connections to them, there's no trivial way to add this in a webserver. You would need to have each child process treated as its own backend, with its own socket, before you could do session affinity to child processes.

Better idea: don't keep the state needed for users in individual processes; persist it outside of the process. That's pretty much what sessions are *for*.

Comment: I'm currently running Octave inside each fcgi instance, which allows Octave to maintain the user's variables between each submission. It seems like the overhead on exporting and re-importing every variable for every submission would be enormous. Any ideas on how to persist Octave's initialized state by user without it being mapped one-to-one with each process?

Comment: You could write an "Octave process server" that spawns Octave processes on demand, accepts connections, and shuttles the data back and forth between the requested process and a socket -- and then your webapp would communicate with the octave server over sockets rather than directly with octave as parent/child. But be prepared for a fair amount of work.

Comment: I'll have to mull this over for a while, but sounds do-able. I appreciate the help.